# Resizing image and changing into grayscale

Tags: python, react-native, rgb, tensorflow.js, grayscale

I'm using my trained model in react native whose input size is 48,48,1. Input values are RGB images. So I tried converting the image into tensor3d, then into grayscale, and resized it. But after resizing the model always gives the same prediction values. I don't understand where something is wrong with my code. My model accuracy is also okay.

```
const imageDataArrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const imageData = new Uint8Array(imageDataArrayBuffer);
let imageTensor = decodeJpeg(imageData).resizeBilinear([48,48]).reshape([48,48,3]);

imageTensor=tf.ones([48,48,3]);
rgb_weights=[0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140];
imageTensor = tf.mul(imageTensor, rgb_weights);
imageTensor = tf.sum(imageTensor, -1);
imageTensor = tf.expandDims(imageTensor, -1);
imageTensor=imageTensor.resizeBilinear([48,48]).reshape([-1,48,48,1]);

let result = await model.predict(imageTensor).data();
alert("Result " +result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that you're ending up with a float32 tensor, because you multiply your `Uint8Array` against a `rgb_weights` and you get a float32 tensor as a result.  If you add `toInt()` to the `tf.mul` you keep the int32 structure in the tensor.

See this example I made where your code works appropriately in creating a grayscale image [LINK TO CODE](https://www.tensorplayground.com/1.0.0/?code=%2F%2F+TensorPlayground.com%0A%2F%2F+RGB+Tensor%0A%2F%2F+INPUT+TENSOR+SHAPE%3A+%5B622%2C1024%2C3%5D%0A%0A%28tf%2C+aTensor%29+%3D%3E+%7B%0A++let+imageTensor%3DaTensor%0A++let+rgb_weights%3D%5B0.2989%2C+0.5870%2C+0.1140%5D%0A++imageTensor+%3D+tf.mul%28imageTensor%2C+rgb_weights%29.toInt%28%29%0A++imageTensor+%3D+tf.sum%28imageTensor%2C+-1%29%0A++imageTensor+%3D+tf.expandDims%28imageTensor%2C+-1%29%0A++imageTensor%3D+imageTensor.resizeBilinear%28%5B48%2C48%5D%29.reshape%28%5B-1%2C48%2C48%2C1%5D%29%0A%0A++return+imageTensor%0A%7D&inputTensor=bella&modelInfo=%7B%7D)

If you remove the `toInt()` on line 8 of my example code, the image is no longer in the correct range.

This also begs the question, what format does your model expect the `imageTensor` to be in?  Do you need to normalize the tensor back to values between 0 to 1 so your model predictions are accurate?  Assure you're respecting the types for each tensor AND for the model.

**Before:**
[image: RGB image input]

**After:**
[image: Grayscale 48x48]

Answer (score 2):

You could chain operators together to convert the image to a grayscale and then you would need to extract the predictions with the use of `dataSync()`.

```
const imageDataArrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const imageData = new Uint8Array(imageDataArrayBuffer);
const imageTensor = decodeJpeg(imageData).resizeBilinear([48,48]).reshape([48,48,3])

# grayscale = (1, width, height, 1)
const grayscale = tf.browser.fromPixels(imageTensor)
    .mean(2)
    .toFloat()
    .expandDims(0)
    .expandDims(-1)

# Extract the results out
const result = await model.predict(imageTensor).dataSync()[0]
```

Comment: unless you wrap chained operations in a `tf.tidy()`, you end up with a memory leak - each operation in a chain creates a new tensor which never gets deallocated - in your case, you end up with 4 versions of image in memory